# Getting two methods invoked .blur() and .click() both at once in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have one input type element on whick i want to bind blur event, and an anchor on which i want to invoke .click() in jquery. here is an example:

```
<a href='#' id='apply-to-all' style='margin-left:10px;'>Apply to All</a>
<input class="controlValue"/>
```

here is my script:

```
$("#apply-to-all").click(function(){
alert("anchor clicked");
});

$('input').bind('blur',function(event){
alert("value set to input");
});
```

this both are working perfect when i click on any part of the page other than anchor. but when i'm putting some value in input type and clicking directly to the anchor "apply to all" then only blur event occurs and click event on the anchor doesn't occurs at all. I want to invoke both the script if enter some data in the input type and after that clicking on the anchor tag, both blur and click event should get invoked to use both the script simultaneously.

Comment: try testing with `console.log` instead of `alert`. the events work as expected. my guesss one alert cancels another one.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function, and call that in both locations...

```
$("#apply-to-all").click(function(){
    alert("anchor clicked");
    myBlurFunction();
});

$('input').blur(function(){
    myBlurFunction();
});

function myBlurFunction(){
   alert("value set to input");
}
```